# Driver not found in Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have read all possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533317/netbeans-with-glassfish-have-no-suitable-driver-found-for-mysqljdbc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622105/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-netbeans) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358). I believe I have a problem somewhere else and it may useful to others also.

I have a Java Servlet and it was executing well in eclipse IDE but later I shifted the project to Netbeans. I imported MySQL JDBC driver in Libraries and using the code below for connection

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bolsms", "root", "@#$5869@#$");
```

but I am getting this error **No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bolsms**

I looking for answer for two days and community will appreciate that I am not repeating the question.

**Edit 1:**

[image: MySQL JDBC driver in Libraries Folder]

Comment: You need to add the driver to the application server library path and restart the app server. Which one are you using? GlassFish?

Comment: @perissf I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0.22.0. As I wrote I have added driver to the Libraries Folder. Let me restart and get back to you.

Comment: @perissf I restarted Netbeans still not working.

Comment: You have shown the application's lib folder. Tomcat's lib folder is a different thing. Moreover, after you have done, you need to the restart Tomcat. Restarting NetBeans is a different thing.

Comment: @perissf Restarting Tomcat doesn't help either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use it in Tomcat you have to explicitly load jdbc driver. I experienced the same error in a servlet in Tomcat. And adding `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` solve it.

The other thing I think, is to put the jar file in your `WEB-INF/lib`, then in your project properties, in Libraries, add the JAR you store in `WEB-INF/lib`.

To create the `lib` directory, right click on `WEB-INF` and choose `New -> Folder...` 
If you don't see `Folder` choose `Other` then in the new windows choose `Other` again and `Folder`.

The Tomcat / JDBC issue is referenced [here](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48214) for more information.

Comment: I tried loading class with Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") but it does not work. Also I quote from Murach's Java Servlet & JSP (IInd Edition) Page 445 **With JDBC 4.0, the database drive is loaded automatically. This feature is known as automatic driver loading.** There is no WEB-INF/lib folder in Netbeans. I reiterate the problem is specific to Netbeans IDE, it was working fine on Eclipse.

Comment: Once again JDBC is loaded automatically yes but not (always) in Tomcat. And my solution works on Netbeans (I don't use Eclipse). If you made a Tomcat project you have a WEB-INF directory for sure. Create the lib directory yourself and add the jar. It's how I do on Netbean. See this link https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48214

Comment: Thanks. I will appreciate if you could edit the answer to include creation of lib folder and bug link in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Include the following piece of code in your code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//load driver
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bolsms", "root", "@#$5869@#$");//connect to the database
```

Comment: Second line code is already there and Loading Driver is not necessary in JDBC 4 which is part of Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

you could also import it using the jsp tag  <%@page import='com.mysql.jdbc.*'%>
or the usual way Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
in the try catch of the jsp page. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your mysql-connector-java-(version)-bin.jar is here:

C:\Murach\Servlets and JSP\jsp2_allfiles\servlet_jsp\netbeans\ex_starts\ch14sqlGateway\build\web\WEB-INF\lib

Also check to see if it is in here:

C:\Murach\Servlets and JSP\jsp2_allfiles\servlet_jsp\netbeans\ex_starts\ch14sqlGateway\web\WEB-INF\lib

If it's not, paste your mysql driver jar into those directories and see if that works.

After that, make sure you're explicitly loading the driver:

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");